# rails script/generate skip unnecessary files by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-generate

Script/generate became very annoying since I started using rspec etc. I dont need unit test files and fixtures anymore, but script/generate makes them anyway.

Is it possible to set `--skip-fixtures` and `--skip-test` to be default system-wide (or at least project-wide)?

Answer (score 6):

You can edit your applications script/generate file to auto append options

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ARGV << "--skip-fixture" if ["model"].include?(ARGV[0])

require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
require 'commands/generate'
```

Comment: I like that you can do that and I always forget, that's why I make aliases instead - so I don't have to do it everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Well, for starters,

```
ruby script/generate rspec_model
ruby script/generate rspec_controller
```

At least that doesn't generate unit tests and it gets the specs there for me :)

But --skip-fixtures still has to get passed. I've just made my own aliases in .bash_profile

```
alias model='ruby script/generate rspec_model $1 --skip-fixture'
```

Then I can just do

```
model bar name:string active:boolean
```

and it all works :)

Answer (score 1):

I use minitest_rails as my testing framework, and you can set some defaults via the config/application.rb file.

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :mini_test, :spec => true, :fixture => false
end
```

When you generate a model (and controller), it will now automatically skip the fixture. This example will also create the Unit Test using the minitest_spec format.